# Pentaho : Cannot view sample fusion charts

Tags: plugins, pentaho, fusioncharts

I Installed and configured fusion charts as instructed in: http://code.google.com/p/pentaho-fc-plugin/wiki/Manual

What is the expected output? Samples should appear in pentaho-solutions/bi-developers in the navigation repository

What do you see instead? For version 0.03, the samples do not appear until you copy the fusion-charts folder into pentaho-solutions/bi-developers of which after you do, the sample dashboard has chart titles only and the rest is blank. The fusion charts free samples produce this error:

> FailedError retrieving data: cdaQueryComponent failed to return data. Query ID:2 Server Version: Pentaho Platform Engine Core 3.10.0-stable.48193I tried installing version 0.03 and the operating system is a 32-bit turnkey linux vm running ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn more about FusionCharts error messages from its documentation - http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?Debug/Basic.html